# The corners of the container edges are not colored - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I would like a rounded ExpansionPanelList with colored borders. I can create the shape and color the edges, but the corners remain colorless. How do I color the corners of the edges too?

Here is a picture and the code I wrote to achieve this:

..................................................................................................................................................................................

[image: 1]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class Item {
  Item({
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List<Item>.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        width: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
              });
            },
            children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
              return ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.headerValue),
                  );
                },
                body: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                    subtitle:
                        const Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _data.removeWhere((Item currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                      });
                    }),
                isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExpansionPanelList displays over the container boundary, which causes this problem. Although it has a rectangular form, you may force the ExpansionPanelList to have the same border radius as the container by enclosing it in the ClipRRect widget. You may get the desired output by just substituting your code with the code below:

```
Container(
  width: 500,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
    child: ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
```